# Fixed header in table layout android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, fixed-header-tables

I need a header to my table layout that doesn't scrolls. I retrieve values from data base so I cant guess the width of the row or column. Each column width will differ. As the data width changes the heading width should also change dynamically and align properly.

I get correct alignment if I use a single table but the header is also scrolling.

I tried with two table layout but not aligned properly.

This is what i need with fixed header

[image]

Comment: can you provide snapshot which you want??

Comment: @AvinashKumarPankaj check the snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use TableFixHeaders which is really useful and has some other benefits as well:

https://github.com/InQBarna/TableFixHeaders

Comment: Will try it and let you know.

Comment: @Yashwanth did this work out for you..? Or did u find another method..?